# Cascading dropdown inside table in blazor

Tags: c#, html, razor, blazor

When changing a row's dropdown, other row's dropdowns are changing too. How to solve this? is it possible to create dynamic methods in each td?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3npGV.png)

```
    <EditForm Model="@model2">
        <table class="table mt-4">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Heading</th>
                    <th>Jump Page</th>
                    <th>Jump Heading</th>
                    <th>Link</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in HeadingList)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.Text</td>



                        <td>
                            <InputSelect ValueExpression="@(() => model2.CountryID)"
                                 ValueChanged="@((int? args) =>
                                                {
                                                    model2.CountryID = args;
                                                    OnPageChangedModel2(args);
                                                })"
                                 class="form-select">
                                <option value="">Select Page...</option>
                                @foreach (var item in PageModel)
                                {
                                    <option value="@item.PageNo">@item.PageNo</option>
                                }
                            </InputSelect>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <InputSelect ValueExpression="@(() => model2.CityID)"
                                 class="form-select">
                                <option value="">Select Page...</option>
                                @foreach (var item in HeadingList2)
                                {
                                    <option value="@item.Text">@item.Text</option>
                                }
                            </InputSelect>
                        </td>





                        <td>
                            <a href="#" class="view-icon">
                                <img src="/img/magnifying-glass-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="view" />
                            </a>

                        </td>

                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        @*<button class="btn btn-dark mb-4 float-end" @onclick="@(e => UpdateButtonClick())">Update</button>*@

    </EditForm>
```

I tried to load data in HeadingList2 whenever the list is refreshing, dropdowns texts are changing too.

Comment: As `Sanchez` said,you need to use list for the first and second dropdowns in for loop.If you want to know how to change the code,you may need to share more code about `OnPageChangedModel2,model2,HeadingList2...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's beacause you've binded controls of every row to the same object (model2).

You probably need to create list of model2 type objects and assign them to elements of HeadingList.